# Get a sublist last 5 elements of LinkedHashSet?

Tags: java, hashset, sublist, linkedhashset

Is there a one liner to get the last 5 elements of a LinkedHashSet in a new LinkedHashSet?

This is what I currently have, but it's not very efficient:

```
new LinkedHashSet<String>(new LinkedList<String>(set)
.subList(Math.max(0, set.size() - 5), set.size());
```

Or should I use for this case a TreeSet, SortedSet, HashSet ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using this:

```
com.google.common.collect.EvictingQueue<E>
```

with this you get to keep only the **last x elements**.

```
EvictingQueue<String> queue = EvictingQueue.create(5);
```

Comment: Please explain how this relates to the question that you asked.  How does it meet your stated requirements / actual requirements?  How are you using it?

Answer (score 0):

If you use Java 8 and you are ok to get back a `HashSet` (instead of a `LinkedHashSet`), you can use the Stream API:

```
Set<String> newSet = set.stream()
                        .skip(set.size() - 5)
                        .collect(Collectors.<String>toSet());
```

Comment: You can have this return a `LinkedHashSet` by changing the collector: `.collect(toCollection(LinkedHashSet::new))`.

Answer (score 0):

Using `ArrayList` you could get a better performance:

```
long s1 = System.nanoTime();
LinkedHashSet<String> last5 = new LinkedHashSet<String>(new LinkedList<String>(set)
        .subList(Math.max(0, set.size() - 5), set.size()));
System.out.println(System.nanoTime() - s1);

s1 = System.nanoTime();
LinkedHashSet<String> usingArrayList = new LinkedHashSet<String>(new ArrayList<String>(set)
        .subList(Math.max(0, set.size() - 5), set.size()));
System.out.println(System.nanoTime() - s1);
```

Comment: Your test is flawed. The second test case benefits from the first case having warmed up the cache. Each test needs to be run in its own runtime invocation.

Comment: @SteveKuo No matter I ran both individually And got better performance :)

Answer (score 0):

Here's the problem.  The iterators for a `LinkedHashSet` are unidirectional; i.e. you can't iterate backwards, even though the underlying data structure has a doubly-linked list.  That means to get the last N you need to iterate to the end of the list.  That is `O(N)`.

In your algorithm, the `LinkedList` constructor is copying the set into a new data structure using (probably) the iterator.

By contrast, the `TreeSet` API has an `descendingIterator()` method that returns an `Iterator` that iterates backwards through the list.  If you use that correctly, you can get the last 5 elements of the set in `O(1)`.  The downside is that adding elements to the set will be `O(logN)` instead of `O(1)` for a hash-based set.

Answer (score 0):

This can be efficiently achieved using the [`reversed()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/LinkedHashSet.html#reversed()) method added to `LinkedHashSet` in Java 21 as part of the [`SequencedSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/SequencedSet.html) interface.

```java
LinkedHashSet<String> lastFive = new LinkedHashSet<>(set.reversed().stream()
        .limit(5).toCollection(LinkedHashSet::new).reversed());
```

This can be simplified to use the `reversed` `Set` directly if the returned set doesn't need to be a `LinkedHashSet`, but just a mutable `Set` with a well-defined iteration order and near-identical characteristics of a `LinkedHashSet`:

```java
SequencedSet<String> lastFive = set.reversed().stream()
        .limit(5).toCollection(LinkedHashSet::new).reversed();
```